# Linkback just can't work in LaTeXiT!

Tags: latexit

I'm new to OS X and LaTeXiT for a week.

I can use the 'Detect and typeset equations' successfully in the 'Service' menu of Pages, then it produces the right things which should be. 
However, I can't double-click the picture to edit the LaTeX code. 
The linkback  just can't work! How can I do? 
Is there something should be set in the preferences in the LaTeXiT?

Here is my screen:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, this is borderline off-topic IMO, but we'll see if anyone knows much about this.